# Merge 2 CSV by Value "Name" and merge Count (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, count

So at the momemt I'm searching for a way to merge 2 CSV files.

Here is an example for what I mean:

CSV1

```
"Name","Count"
"Klaus","3"
"Hans","2"
"Gerhard","1"
"Nina","6"
"Julia","10"
"Caro","19"
```

CSV2

```
"Name","Count"
"Klaus","2"
"Hans","1"
"Gerhard","1"
"Nina","1"
```

Now if I merge both, the output/result should be:

```
"Name","Count"
"Klaus","5"
"Hans","3"
"Gerhard","2"
"Nina","7"
"Julia","10"
"Caro","19"
```

I tried a lot, but I´ve never had suscess; I always had wrong results.  Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the code in PowerShell you used to see what you did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Group-Object` (alias `group`) to group everything by the `Name` property.  Then you just need to sum up the `Count` property of each guy in the group.  `Measure-Object` (alias `measure`) will do sums for you.

```
$grouped = Import-Csv .\csv1.csv, .\csv2.csv | group Name
$combined = $grouped |%{ 
   New-Object PsObject -Prop @{ Name = $_.Name; Count = ($_.Group | measure -sum -prop Count).Sum }
}
$combined | Export-Csv .\combined.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Suggest using `Export-Csv -notype` to avoid getting the type info in the output file.

Comment: @latkin: Thank you for your answer! Works perfeclty. I didnt thought this would be so easy

Comment: Okay im completly dumb at the moment!
Lets say i have a CSV like CSV1 (but a lot bigger)
If i do now:
import-csv csv1 | sort count -descending; It doesnt sort it proper. It seems like it ignores Count....
Do you have an idea? I feel so stupid now... I don´t know why it doesnt work

Comment: Please mark my response as the answer if it solved your problem, then others will know your question has been answered.

Comment: Regarding the sort issue - without any other info, `Import-Csv` has to assume all fields are strings.  So you are sorting based on the **string** of Count.  You want to sort based on the **int** value of Count.  Do this:  `Import-Csv .\Csv1.csv | sort {[int] $_.Count} -Descending`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. ANd sorry for not marking your Answer. Did it now. (im not used to this Website, sorry again)

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV files and convert each to a hash table, then find the common names:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path csv2.csv

$HashCSV1 = @{}
$HashCSV2 = @{}
$HashMerge = @{}

foreach($r in $csv1)
{
    $HashCSV1[$r.Name] = $r.Count
}

foreach($r in $csv2)
{
    $HashCSV2[$r.Name] = $r.Count
}

foreach ($key in $HashCSV1.Keys) { 
    if ($HashCSV2.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $HashMerge[$key] = [int]$HashCSV1[$key] + [int]$HashCSV2[$key]
    } else {
        $HashMerge[$key] = $HashCSV1[$key]
    }
}

foreach ($key in $HashCSV2.Keys) { 
    if (-not $HashCSV1.ContainsKey($key)) {
        $HashMerge[$key] = $HashCSV2[$key]
    }
}

&{$HashMerge.getenumerator() |
  foreach {new-object psobject -Property @{Name = $_.name;Count=$_.value}}
  } | export-csv merge.csv -notype
```

Comment: This will discard any names in CSV2 which are not in CSV1

Comment: @Coral Doe: This is what i tried
[meta]
$neu = import-csv today.csv
$full = import-csv complete.csv
$names= $full | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$row = 0
foreach ($name in $neu) {
if ($names -contains $neu[$row].name)
{
[int]$full[($names | Select-String ($neu[$row].name)).linenumber-1].count = [int]$full[($names | Select-String ($neu[$row].name)).linenumber-1].count + [int]@($neu[$row]).count
}
$row++
}
[/meta]
This is one of my tries. I know it will fail somehow (it doesnt work for Names not in the other csv but it even doesnt work at all)  . Edit: I have a little problem with the Editor here